How to reduce the dataset size with Power BI date slicers for Vega lite visual?
I am new to Vega lite.
Potentially I have over one million rows in a Power BI table. Each row has an associated time stamp. I want to reduce the dataset size with the start and end date slicer in Power BI before forwarding the reduced dataset to Deneb visual in Vega lite.
This image shows both ordinal and date slicers working fine in Power BI report.

However, the dataset still has October 25 in Deneb. How to filter out those rows before passing in the dataset? I could use filter transform to filter out October 25 for the display, but I don’t want to.  The goal is to reduce the dataset size in Deneb for performance.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IpaO29aDD9LgVqg1Bd_1aWJsZuWIHNhw/view?usp=drive_link is my .pbix.
Thank you.
I have tried using DAX calculatetable() function to create a new dynamic physical table holding reduced dataset, but resulting table is always empty.
